# Arrange NSDictionary unique value in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

Hi i am getting response form Json like this

```
{"items":[{"f":"djay","m":"hi ajay","d":"2012-9-22","id":"16"},{"f":"djay","m":"hi","d":"2012-9-22","id":"25"},{"f":"Chithri","m":"hi","d":"2012-9-23","id":"26"},{"f":"ChithriAtchibabu","m":"gig","d":"2012-9-23","id":"27"}]}
```

i want arrange my array like this

```
   [{"time":"2012-9-22","data":[{"m":"hiajay"},{"m":hi}]},{"time":"2012-9-23","data":[{"m":"hi"},{"m":gig}]}]
```

can any one please guide me how could i arrange my array like this

Comment: there is a quite big difference between NSDictionary and NSArray. In title you wrote about first, in details you tell about NSArray. So which one you want to use ?

Comment: {"m":"hiajay","m":hi} you can not assign same keys twice in a dictionary

Comment: why do you want to arrange the data ? is there any specific reason for this ??

Answer (score 1):

An NSDictionary is an unsorted collection.

To sort the data in it makes no sense.

What you are doing in your post is completely rebuilding an array of dictionaries from another dictionary.

Also, a dictionary can't have duplicate keys.

To do this you'd have to go through the array "items" in your first dictionary and then create a new dictionary for each new date and then inside there put an array with the items in it.  Or something...